# JavaFX buttons click order

Tags: java, button, javafx

So I have 3 Buttons - red, yellow and green. The user should click them in the right order - from red to green. If this happens, it will say "OK" and if not, it will say "Wrong" or whatever. I'm stuck, because I don't know how to correctly get the click order.

This is what i have for now, but it doesn't work properly.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox root = new VBox();

    Button b1 = new Button("Red");
    Button b2 = new Button("Yellow");
    Button b3 = new Button("Green");

    root.getChildren().add(b1);
    root.getChildren().add(b2);
    root.getChildren().add(b3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Traffic");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();

    b1.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
        b2.setOnAction((ActionEvent t1) -> {
            b3.setOnAction((ActionEvent t2) -> {
                System.out.println("OK");
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of which button is next:

```
private Button nextButton ;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox root = new VBox();

    Button b1 = new Button("Red");
    Button b2 = new Button("Yellow");
    Button b3 = new Button("Green");

    nextButton = b1 ;

    root.getChildren().add(b1);
    root.getChildren().add(b2);
    root.getChildren().add(b3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Traffic");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();

    b1.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
        if (nextButton==b1) {
            nextButton=b2 ;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    });

    b2.setOnAction((ActionEvent t1) -> {
        // etc
    });

    b3.setOnAction((ActionEvent t2) -> {
        // etc
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make 3 bool variables, one for each button. 
For example : redButtonPressed, yellowButtonPressed, greenButtonPressed. 
All initialize to false.

Then, when red button is pressed, set redButtonPressed to true.
When yellow button is pressed:

```
if (redButtonPressed){
yellowButtonPressed = true;
} else {
print "Wrong!";
}
```

and for green button, when it is pressed :

```
if(redButtonPressed && yellowButtonPressed){
print "OK";
} else {
print "Wrong!";
}
```

after printing "Wrong" you should set all bools to false i think.

Comment: I need to print it.